# File selection dialog popup underlays behind chrome extension popup window

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extension, web-deployment, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

In my browser extension, I am trying to upload a file from my computer. When I click on "select a file" option inside my browser (), the file selection dialog box underlays behind the popup window.
This appears only when the browser is in full screen mode and on MAC OS. Once I switch the tab or remove full screen mode it overlays as expected.

Can someone please provide a solution or workaround to this issue?

[image: Attached screenshot for reference]

Comment: Do you have a Github repository, or something similar, where we can download the source code for your extension?

Comment: This is a bug in Chrome. You will have to open the popup as a separate window or embed it into the web page as an iframe via web_accessible_resources.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue recently with a Chrome extension. How did the issue appear? I don't think I've changed anything, it seems to have appeared out of nowhere.
If you have any insights, I'm interested in collaborating with you to debug the issue with my own extension. Let me know!

Comment: @Sonali Agrawal did you manage to solve the issue in your extension?

Comment: Hi. Thomas. This is not really an answer - rather a comment. Maybe next time use the comment section for that.